# hashing password in registration different from the login password

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, md5

I have a registration page that allows users to insert a password. I hash the password upon registration so that it is stored more securely in the database.

When the user logs in with the same password, the two hashes don't match and the user cannot log in.

This is my first time using a hash and it didn't behave as I expected:

**This is the hashing code on the registration page:**

```
$salt ="";     
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$test$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass1);      
echo $hashedpass;
//************Insert all the members's input to the database**************************//
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(user_name, first_name, last_name, governorate, district, village, birth_date, email_address, specialization, password, salt, registered_date )VALUES('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$governorate', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$hashedpass', '$salt',  now())")or die(mysql_error());
```

i did add salt but it give empty

**This is the hashing code on the login page**

```
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$test$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass);   
echo $hashedpass;


$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name, user_name FROM members WHERE email_address='$email'AND password= '$hashedpass' LIMIT 1") or die("error in members table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)the hashing password = $2y$09$test$4ZGgCiXdKzgQvuzwu.AxfdWvZadDCE.LD6HCkrK3ZsqJeN7e
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user registers you need to store both the salt and the hashed password in your database. When the user tries to log in you need to use the **same salt** as when they registered, otherwise the hash will be different. This is called a per-user salt and is the more secure option.

A simpler, though less-secure option would be to generate a single salt value for the application and use it for all users. This will have the effect of keeping all the passwords hashed in the database but is much less secure because if that salt value is compromised it's a trivial matter to brute-force the hashed passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the salt in the database, together with the hashed password.

When the user tries to login, you need to get the salt from the database, and hash the user input with it, to compare it against the hashed password.

In your example, you're generating a random salt in the login procedure which will never produce the same hash as you have in your database.

Comment: so in my example what it should be the code because it did not workk as it should

Comment: When the user registers, you generate a salt, and hash the password with it. Then you save both of the passwords in to your database. When the users tries to log in, the first thing you do, is getting the salt of the user. Once you have his salt, you can hash the password entered by the user with the salt from the database. Then you can compare the generated hash with the hash in your database.

Comment: the problem is i do not understand what you mean by getting the salt of the user  (in the code i do not know what to write)

Comment: Do you have a database?

Comment: yes  members table contain email and password  with other fields

Comment: Does your members table have a column for the salt?

Comment: ahhhhhh no just a email and password concerning  this part

Comment: Ok, create a column for salt. Then in the registration process, you put your generated salt into the members table. When the user logs in, you **don't** create a new salt, you read the salt from the database.

Comment: ok i will try this and  display the update question hope that i will make it work

Comment: edit question see above

Comment: @user2398286 It's still the same as it was 10 minutes ago?

Comment: i did edit now take a look

Comment: You now store the salt in the database, but you don't read the salt when the user logs in (you still generate a **new** salt).

Comment: no the salt is not stored in the database because is still empty

Comment: sir if i remember the registered password din a session is that write than i can use it in the login file

Comment: I didn't use PHP for a while, but as far as I know you can't use the variable **$salt** outside of your function **cryptPass**. Since you really don't seem to be much into this materia, I'd suggest using some external library which handles the login.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to write it yourself, you need to store the generated salts in the DB (as the other responders said). More generally, I would try to delegate as much as possible to an outside library that provides password support out of the box. Getting crypto right is hard, and you really need to read up a bit more before you start rolling it yourself. There's good library support out there. You should use it.

Also, you really shouldn't be using MD5 to hash the passwords. Use bcrypt, pbkdf2, or another hash suitable for passwords. Just use a library.

Answer (score 0):

Password salting works by appending a pre-defined random set of plaintext to a password before hashing it. This avoids having two identical hashes for two users having chosen the same password. Imagine two users of your system, user1 and user2, choosing '*letmein*' as a password:

```
salt_user1 = 'awoidjalskdm'   
hash = MD5('letmein'+salt_user1) = ab82a9c495e3fe88d1986176e4850b1d
```

and for user2

```
salt_user2 = 'duiesnblekfn'
hash = MD5('letmein'+salt_user2) = 69caac44b5ee9f8b6468b5625000723a
```

Assuming your database structure is something along the lines of username:salt:password_hash, you would have this:

```
user1:awoidjalskdm:ab82a9c495e3fe88d1986176e4850b1d
user2:duiesnblekfn:69caac44b5ee9f8b6468b5625000723a
```

The main aim of password salting is to avoid mass password compromise if your database gets compromised. Password salting will make it tougher to bruteforce simple and popular passwords that are chosen by several different users.

**In your case**, it seems that you are generating salts randomly for registration (which is good). The mistake seems to be in the login function, where you re-calculate a random salt instead of retrieving the one that had been generated earlier and that should have been stored.

The salt you're appending to your password before hashing it needs to be the same for each user, and you need to be able to recall it when you need it. Even though it might seem contradictory, this means it has to be stored in plaintext in the database.